# No output is displaying from Session Bean via Managed bean to JSF page

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, jsf-2.2

I am new in Java EE. So I cannot find the solution! Could you anybody figure out?

Session Bean:

```
package services;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HelloService {

    public String getHelloString() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Managed bean:

```
package beans;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import services.HelloService;

@Named(value = "helloBean")
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean {
    @EJB
    private HelloService helloService;


    private String hello;

    public HelloBean() {
    }

    public String getHello() {
        hello = helloService.getHelloString();
        return hello;
    }

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

}
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText value="#{helloBean.hello}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

POM.xml of web module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>HRM</artifactId>
    <groupId>iqbal</groupId>
    <version>1.0-Snapshot</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>iqbal</groupId>
    <artifactId>HRM-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-Snapshot</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>HRM-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>HRM-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-Snapshot</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

But in index.xhtml there is no output! Maven is build successfully and the page has been opened in browser. But no output!

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: On which server do you run the project? Do you even have EJB and CDI?